# Get message headers in batch mode

Tags: header, spring-batch, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In a spring-cloud-stream Kafka application, when consuming messages in regular mode I get the Message with its payload and custom headers properly. yet, when I set the consumer "headerMode" to true and the Function's input type to List<?> (according to documentation), I get a list of payloads. How can I get a list of Messages, each containing header and payload?

clarification - event when setting the collection type (e.g. `List<Message<MyType>>`, its always returning just the payloads (`List<MyType>`) on runtime.

application.yaml:

```
spring:
cloud:
    function:
        definition: function
    stream:
        default-binder: my-avro-binder
        bindings:
            function-in-0:
                binder: my-avro-binder
                destination: function-output
                group: constant-name
                contentType: application/*+avro
                consumer:
                    useNativeEncoding: true
                    batchMode: true
                    headerMode: headers
```

binder definition:

```
 kafka-string-avro:
      type: kafka
      environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties:
        key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
        value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
        schema.registry.url: ${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:http://localhost:8081}
        specific.avro.reader: true
```

function definition:

```
@Bean
public Function<List<?>, List<Message<MyType>>> function() {
    Function<List<?>, List<Message<MyType>>> func =
            list -> {
                // logic...
                return list;
            };
    return func;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @GaryRussell, after some more trials here is I did:

1. added `contentType: application/*+avro` property to my consumer binding (otherwise it wouldn't work).
2. the supplied headers are found within the `Kafka_batchConvertedHeaders` header key, supplied as list of maps, each representing all headers map of a single message.

Comment: If you want to say thank you to a user, consider upvoting his answer instead of just mentioning it here. This is not what in an answer should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Message<List<Type>>` the headers contain lists of headers (in the same order as the payloads).

e.g. `getHeader().get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, List.class)` returns a `List<Long>`.

Comment: Garry the Message<List<Type>> is not working for spring boot 2.7.8 and cloud 2021.0.5, the payload is null. but the payload gets serialized once I change it to List<Type>

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. Ask a new question showing your code and configuration.

Comment: i found an issue in spring cloud stream and spring cloud sleuth, I will post a a question for it very sson